# Unable to trigger build using 'Poll SCM' and Git notifyCommit option

Tags: git, jenkins, githooks

We use Jenkins (1.614) and have Git as version control tool. The Git plugin version is 2.3.5. I am trying to trigger build *only* after every check-in since *continuously* polling is too expensive. I tried the following method described in various links but it’s not working:

1. Enabled ‘Poll SCM’ and assigned a dummy value. I also tried without assigning any value.
2. Added following line in post-receive hook:

```css
curl http://jenkins_url:9099/jenkins/git/notifyCommit?url=ssh://gitolite@git_server/TestRepo
```

3. Now if I commit some changes, I get the following message during push:

```css
$ git push origin release-test
Counting objects: 20, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 308 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Commit ID: 3a9cddadasd
remote: Returning result 0
remote:   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
remote:                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
remote: 124   124  124   124    0     0     30      0  0:00:04  0:00:04 --:--:--   497
remote: Scheduled polling of Poll_Job
remote: No Git consumers using SCM API plugin for: ssh://gitolite@git_server/TestRepo
```

4. When I see the Git Polling Log, I notice the following:

```css
Started on Jun 10, 2015 6:42:04 PM
No existing build. Scheduling a new one.
Done. Took 0 ms
Changes found
```

I do see the build # getting incremented after every such poll for few seconds but 'Build History' remains empty as shown below. No steps that are part of the build are executed.

[image]

Any inputs why the build is not getting triggered as expected?

Comment: Wild guess: I think your Jenkins disk is out of sync, try going to your admin and select "Reload Configurations from Disk"

Comment: Tried your suggestion but didn't work :(

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the build "**Git Polling Log**", it might indicate the problem. I had similar issue where Maven job with a trigger by "Poll SCM" from Git, stopped triggering new builds. Apparently the cause was:

> ERROR: Failed to record SCM polling ...
>   undefined method `add' for nil:NilClass
>   at Jenkins::Model::Build.initialize(C:/Jenkins/plugins/nodeofflinenotification/ ...

Then I noticed that "Node Offline Notification Plugin" is deprecated, so I uninstalled it (and installed "Mail Watcher Plugin" instead), and SCM polling worked again.

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, it seems the issue is with the git-plugin as discussed [here](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28865). I’m waiting for the fix which should hopefully come by this month end. :)